# Suggestion needed for distributed storage for hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ipfs

I'm developing a node application to interact with hyperledger fabric. In this application we need to store some files in distributed storage and after storing file, I'll store its reference (hash) to fabric. I have read about IPFS as a distributed storage. But, I need some suggestions is there any other distributed storage that we can use with hyperledger.

Comment: I would suggest to check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401957/best-practice-to-save-files-in-blockchain), It has the answer that you ask for

Answer (score 0):

Given you are trying to store files external to your Fabric peer node(s), you can use any storage or file system you want.  Which storage you pick depends on your actual requirements for the storage of the files in terms of trust, replication, security, etc.